# thumbnails of videos in LUKS partition not getting generated

Tags: partitioning, encryption, luks, thumbnails

i encrypted a partitions using LUKS but now video thumbnails are not generating (in that particular partition) although image thumbnails are there, i tried with the ffmpegthumbnailer command but not working,
kindly suggest is there any solution.

Comment: Which partition did you encrypt, and where are the videos stored? Where do you expect to see the thumbnails?

Comment: /dev/sda4 is the partition and videos stored on that partition are not getting any thumbnails in file manager(default)

Comment: And the partition is mounted I suppose, and it is not your home partition? Honestly I don't know what the problem could be, but I would check the permissions on that partition.

Comment: yes it is mounted and the permissions of the partition are set to create and delete files for all (owner,group and others), but i don't think that is the problem as my images are getting thumbnails

Comment: and its not my home partition